# Why is SQL Server Pivot being case sensitive on TabTypeId instead of treating it as the actual column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

In T-Sql I am parsing JSON and using `PIVOT`.

```
Select * from (select [key],convert(varchar,[value])[value] 
from openjson ('{"Name":"tew","TabTypeId":9,"Type":3}'))A
    pivot(max(value) for [key] in ([Name],tabTypeId,[Type]))b
```

It is not treating `tabTypeId` as equal to `TabTypeId`. I am getting `NULL` for `tabTypeId`.
If I use `TabTypeId` I get the value `9`.
Why is it happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not `PIVOT` that is case sensitive, it's the data returned from `OPENJSON` that is. If you check the data returned from it, you'll see that the column `key` is a binary collation:

```sql
SELECT name, system_type_name, collation_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT [key], CONVERT(varchar, [value]) AS [value] FROM OPENJSON(''{"Name":"tew","TabTypeId":9,"Type":3}'');',NULL,NULL)
```

| name | system_type_name | collation_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| key | nvarchar(4000) | Latin1_General_BIN2 |
| value | varchar(30) | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |

For binary collations the actual *bytes* of the characters must match. As such `N'tabTypeId'` and `N'TabTypeId'` are **not** equal as `N'T'` and `N't'` have the `binary` values `0x5400` and `0x7400`.

Though I am unsure why you are using `PIVOT` at all; just define your columns in your `OPENJSON` call:

```sql
SELECT name, --Columns are intentionally demonstrating non-case sensitivity
       tabTypeId,
       type
FROM OPENJSON('{"Name":"tew","TabTypeId":9,"Type":3}')
        WITH (Name varchar(3),
              TabTypeId int,
              Type int);
```

Note that in the `WITH` clause of `OPENJSON` the column names are still case sensitive. `tabTypeId int` would also yield `NULL`. If you "had" to have a column called `tabTypeId` defined *prior* to the `SELECT` you would use `tabTypeId int '$.TabTypeId'` instead.

Comment: ok Thank you. some jsons have TabTypeID and some tabtypeID. Even in with clause I need to specify the same case. How to overcome this.

Comment: Fix the JSON, @Narendra , would be my first suggestion. Otherwise return columns for *both* `TabTypeId` and `tabTypeId` and then use an `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` in the `SELECT`. But, again, fixing the JSON is the *correct* solution in my opinion.

Comment: so what i have done is,I have added lower(value) in my query and used the lowercase in pivot column names.

Comment: I *assume* you mean `LOWER([Key])` @Narendra , as `value` inherets to collation of the database, and presumably your database isn't in a case sensitive collation (as otherwise this questions seem somewhat silly as *all* objects would case sensitive then).

Comment: yeah i meant key

Comment: you can also re-collate the key when returning i guess: ...select [key] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as [key] ...